# Import automated test results to Xray Cloud multipart using Azure Devops

Tags: java, azure-devops, testng, multipart, jira-xray

I am trying to import results to Xray Cloud multipart using Azure Devops, this is my bash command from the yml configuration file:

```
     token=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{ "client_id": "$(client_id)","client_secret": "$(client_secret)" }' https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v1/authenticate| tr -d '"')
     curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -X POST -F info=@path\issueFields.json -F results=@path\target\surefire-reports\TEST-TestSuite.xml -F testInfo=@path\testIssueFields.json -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v1/import/execution/testng/multipart"
```

I am receiving this error everytime in the pipeline console:

```
"curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
##[error]Bash exited with code '26'."
```

What am I doing wrong?

The bash log:

```
Starting: Bash
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.189.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
```

Comment: What agent your are using, hosted agent? And the windows agent or Nexus? please share the debug log in the question.

Comment: Hi @Leo, I have added the debug log in the question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the commands exactly as you shared then you must have a file named "path\issueFields.json". I guess that "path" is not a real directory name. The same applies to other files you identify.
So probably your curl command should be just something like:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -X POST -F info=@issueFields.json -F results=@./target/surefire-reports/TEST-TestSuite.xml -F testInfo=@testIssueFields.json -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v1/import/execution/testng/multipart"
```

Comment: Sergio, "path" was the absolute path of the file location. Also I have tried your curl command exactly as it was written by you but I have the same result :(

Comment: do you have all those files? can you also try replacing / for \  on the path as it seems you're using a windows system?

Comment: yes, the json files are in the root directory and the xml file is in the surefire-reports folder

Comment: replacing the  / for \ didnt work out in the filepaths?

Comment: I have replaced the / for \ but still didn't work

Comment: maybe there's some problem with your path in terms of characters. Can you try adding the path between "", something like

curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -X POST -F info=@"issueFields.json" -F results=@"target\surefire-reports\TEST-TestSuite.xml" -F testInfo=@"testIssueFields.json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v1/import/execution/testng/multipart"

Comment: Thank you Sergio for your help. This is what worked: curl -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -X POST -F info=@issueFields.json -F results=@C:/IdeaProjects/MyProject/target/surefire-reports/TEST-TestSuite.xml -F testInfo=@testIssueFields.json -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" https://xray.cloud.xpand-it.com/api/v1/import/execution/testng/multipart. Basically I have added the full path of the xml results + I have replace the \ with / instead and it worked after that, the test results are importing to jira.

Answer (score 1):

One more way of achieving this is by automating the XRay API in PowerShell.

Here's how to achieve this:

1. Add a "PowerShell" task in your Azure Pipeline.
2. Select "Type" as "Inline".
3. Enter this script:

> $Body = @{
> client_id = ""
> client_secret = "" }
>
> $Parameters = @{
> Method = "POST"
> Uri =  "https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v1/authenticate"
> Body = $Body
> ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
>
> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =
> [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
>
> $token = Invoke-RestMethod @Parameters
>
> $Header = @{
> "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"
> }
>
> $FileContent =
> [IO.File]::ReadAllText('$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\EnterYourResultFilePath');
>
> $Parameters = @{
> Method = "POST"
> Uri =  "https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v1/import/execution/junit?projectKey=ABCD&testPlanKey=ABCD-$(TestPlanKey)"
> Body = $FileContent
> Headers     = $Header
> ContentType = "application/xml" }
>
> ```
> Invoke-RestMethod @Parameters
> ```

I use this script to upload results to JIRA from an XML file.

Comment: Thanks Jaideep, i just saw your answer and this is very useful as well